# Synthesis of Almotritpane - mechanism for educational purpose

Tags: organic-chemistry

I purposed a full mechanism of the almotriptane synthesis.
I wanted to help my fellow students and myself.
Could you give me any tips? Are there any mistakes? I posted the SnCl2 reduction already, but I proposed a second mechanism and cant decide which one is right.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Mechanism of the Fischer-indole synthesis                                               http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/fischerindoleigtlcb3yfk.png

Comment: proposed mechanism of the methylation http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/methylationprin3ypgqkt2j.png

Comment: Is it correct to say that your question is about *DMF followed by Methylation with MeI* vs *Formaldehyde followed by borohydride reduction*?

Comment: No DMF is only the solvent for the reduction with Raney-Nickel. It should explain the whole synthesis and the reactions with mechanism.

Comment: trying to figure out what the question is because you mention second mechanism, not sure if you meant the section labeled "2) proposed reduction mechanism" or the last section above "1) proposed net reaction".

Comment: Also, for the last step with Borohydride you would only get one methyl group and not two. You would have to do it twice, don't think you can do it in one pot because the formaldehyde in excess would react with the Borohydride first.

Comment: Like this http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/methylationprij7upc2rn0y.png ?

Comment: second mechanism is the 3rd one my fault ... the 2 proposed mechanisms are 2) (first) 3) (second)

Comment: Not too familiar with the reduction for that, sorry. But I did find a better way to make your dimethyl instead of doing the borohydride reduction twice: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eschweiler%E2%80%93Clarke_reaction

Comment: Wow, thats a really good reaction. Thank you.

Comment: Like this: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-30917534/methylation_primary_amine_methanal_methanoic_acid.png.html